# Unable to find a SpringBootConfiguration in Spring Boot Test 1.4

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, testing, spring-boot, spring-test

I'm not able to run a simple test in spring boot 1.4. I followed the tutorial from the official site [testing-the-spring-mvc-slice](https://spring.io/blog/2016/04/15/testing-improvements-in-spring-boot-1-4#testing-the-spring-mvc-slice) but I didn't get it to work.

every time i get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to find a @SpringBootConfiguration, you need to use @ContextConfiguration or @SpringBootTest(classes=...) with your test
```

any ideas, hints?

Thanks in advance

**Edit:**

this is the controller

```
@Controller
public class UserManagementController {

@GetMapping(value = "/gs/users/getUsers")
    public @ResponseBody String getAllUsers() {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

this is the test

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(UserManagementController.class)
public class UserManagementControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Test
    public void showUserView() throws Exception {
        this.mvc.perform(get("/gs/users/getUsers"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andDo(print());
    }
}
```

From my point of view it's exactly the same like this post from the site.

the `@WebMvcTest` will do:

- Auto-configure Spring MVC, Jackson, Gson, Message converters etc.
- Load relevant components (`@Controller`, `@RestController`, `@JsonComponent` etc)
- Configure MockMVC

now why i need to configure a "super" class

Comment: like the msg says, use one of the other annotations

Comment: Yes that's right. But in the official docs they say you can use that and it's enough.

Comment: if you provide you tested class and test itself it could be more clear

Comment: @ManuZi i've updated my answer, it work's for me, hope it help you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> The search algorithm works up from the package that contains the test
>   until it finds a @SpringBootApplication or @SpringBootConfiguration
>   annotated class. As long as you’ve structure your code in a sensible
>   way your main configuration is usually found.

So you have annotated your test with **@*Test**. It run, checked for configuration in subclasses, haven't found any, thrown an exception.

You have to have a config in a package or subpackage of test class or directly pass config class to `@ContextConfiguration` or `@SpringBootTest` or have class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`.

According to `@SpringBootApplication`. I have tested controller in way you have mentioned with `@WebMvcTest`: it works if application has class annotated as `@SpringBootApplication` and fails with exception you've mentioned if not. There is remark it the article you mentioned:

> In this example, we’ve omitted classes which means that the test will
>   first attempt to load @Configuration from any inner-classes, and if
>   that fails, it will search for your primary @SpringBootApplication
>   class.

Github [discussion](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5987) about the same point.

[Spring Boot Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.0.M3/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-detecting-config)

Comment: I have same problem. I would want to avoid pointing to my main production configuration, since it loads all database stuff and simple test lasts too long. I thought @WebMvcTest loads the lightweight configuration (no db, minimal networking), so I will mock the service layer and quickly test controller logic. But it looks like to test controllers I have to test full stack always, create DB objects etc.