# Can't find @SpringBootApplication from JUnit test file

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit

I was following the guide here, https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/  - cloned the project, built with Gradle and tried to run...application ran fine. Then I changed some file structure as per my requirement and tried to run the unit test case given there, but getting this error -

> Unable to find a @SpringBootConfiguration, you need to use @ContextConfiguration or @SpringBootTest(classes=...) with your test

I only restructure the codes in there, and this is my current project structure -

```
/projectroot
    - /src/main/java
          -Application.java
          -/controller
               -MyController.java
          -/util
               -MyUtil.java
          -/model
               -MyModel.java
```

Now trying to run test case from

> /src/test/java/controller/MyControllerTest.java

I have gone through this [Stack Overflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40215606/unable-to-find-a-springbootconfiguration-in-spring-boot-test-1-4) and understood that if I put my test folder under /src/main/java/ it may work. But if I do that test file doesn't compile and it also doesn't seem the right way to put application code along with test code. I know I'm missing something very fundamental.

Answer (score 2):

The way you setup your test (using the whole spring boot context), I believe `MyControllerTest.java` needs to be at most at the same level as `Application.java`. Also, I notice `Application.java` is using **default package**, you should move it into a package, so that all your beans are **below** your Spring Boot main class:

```
/projectroot
    - /src/main/java/com/example/project/
          -Application.java
          -/controller
               -MyController.java
          -/util
               -MyUtil.java
          -/model
               -MyModel.java
    - /src/test/java/com/example/project/
          -MyControllerTest.java
```

[Spring's documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-detecting-config)

**How Spring Boot's context is resolved from a test**:

> The search algorithm works up from the package that contains the test
>   until it finds a @SpringBootApplication or @SpringBootConfiguration
>   annotated class. As long as you’ve structure your code in a sensible
>   way your main configuration is usually found.

**About using the default package with Spring Boot**:

> When a class doesn’t include a package declaration it is considered to
>   be in the “default package”. The use of the “default package” is
>   generally discouraged, and should be avoided. It can cause particular
>   problems for Spring Boot applications that use @ComponentScan,
>   @EntityScan or @SpringBootApplication annotations, since every class
>   from every jar, will be read.
>
> We recommend that you follow Java’s recommended package naming conventions and use a reversed domain name (for example, com.example.project).

Comment: Thanks, this fixed my issue. You are a life saver :).